# logarithm and square inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How would you approach an inequality like $$10x*\ln(x) > 2x^2?$$

I have tried to just solve it by changing it to $$0 > 2x(x - 5\ln(x)).$$
However, I think my solution is wrong.

Comment: You cannot find an algebraic solution for this. You will need some kind of numerical method.

Comment: This equality doesn't hold at all try $x=e^{10}$

Comment: @Paul Alternatively, this is what the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) was made to do. So there is an analytical solution using that.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz We're not proving that it holds for all $x$, we're trying to find which $x$ makes it true. I think...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Not true!

Comment: In fact this holds for $x_1<x<x_2$ where $x_1$ and $x_2>x_1$ are two distinct positive roots of $e^{x}=x^5$

Comment: I used a graphic calculator to get an idea of what the answer is. It seems the inequality holds for $x>1.2958555\dots$, which I don't immediately recognise.

Comment: That's right it has only one root!

Comment: You need $x \gt 0$ to have a real logarithm.  You can then divide through by $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality becomes $\ln(x)>\frac15x$ (we can divide by $x$ without any problems, because the presence of a logarithm means $x$ is strictly positive anyways). Now, since both sides of this inequality are continuous, we can look for equality, and solve the inequality later: 
$$
\ln(x)=\frac15x\\
x = e^{x/5}\\
xe^{-x/5} = 1\\
-\frac{x}5e^{-x/5}=-\frac15\\
W\left(-\frac{x}5e^{-x/5}\right)=W(-1/5)\\
-\frac x5 = W(-1/5)\\
x = -5W(-1/5)
$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Its value at $-1/5$ is approximately $-0.26$, so the answer to our equation is $-5\cdot -0.26 = 1.3$.

However, just like when we use square roots to solve equations, there may be more solutions, because the Lambert $W$ function is the inverse of a non-injective function. In fact, for every number between $-1/e$ and $0$, there are *two* values to $W$, just like there are really two values to $\sqrt{{}\cdot{}}$ for positive input (usually signified by $\pm \sqrt{{}\cdot{}}$).

The second value, given by a function called $W_{-1}$ by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*e%5Ex+%3D+-1%2F5), which is where I did all the actual calculations here, gives us $$x = -5W_{-1}(-1/5) \approx -5\cdot -2.54 = 12.7$$

So, we now have our points where the right-hand side and left-hand side are equal, and a simple inspection will show that the inequality is satisfied when $x$ is *between* these two points, but not otherwise.

Comment: PS. When I first met the Lambert $W$ I didn't like it. It felt like cheating. I have since realized that it is no different, at least for equation solving purposes, from $\ln$ or $\sqrt{{}\cdot{}}$ or a whole lot of other commonly used functions. I still haven't learned how to use it efficiently in more complicated equations, but something like this I can manage.

Comment: Nice comment below your answer, I too am uncomfortable with the use of $W$ and have tried to understand it more as a function like $\ln$, it's nice to know I'm not the only one! +1

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the inequality then use a computer program to find the region where the inequality is true.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
    &10x  \ln(x) > 2x^2\\
    &\ln(x) > \frac{1}{5} x\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

From here, we switch to the numerical approach. I've used sagemath for this. A plot of $\ln(x)$ and $\frac{1}{5} x$ reveals the boundary points of the inequality:
[image]

Now we can compute the boundary numerically:

```
sage: f = log(x) == x/5
sage: find_root(f, 0, 20)
12.713206788867632
find_root(f, 1, 2)
1.2958555090953687
```

So $10x\ln(x) > 2x^2$ in the interval $1.2958555090953687 < x < 12.713206788867632$